# Creating column with counter for Months in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following R data frame:

```
ID     Completed       Days
001    Yes             65
002    No              NA
003    Yes             120
004    Yes             22
```

I would like to create the following data set:

```
ID     Month           Success          DaysAtSuccess
001    1               No                 NA
002    1               No                 NA
003    1               No                 NA 
004    1               Yes                22
001    2               No                 NA
002    2               No                 NA
003    2               No                 NA 
004    2               Yes                22
001    3               Yes                65
002    3               No                 NA
003    3               No                 NA 
004    3               Yes                22
001    4               Yes                65
002    4               No                 NA
003    4               Yes               120
004    4               Yes                22
```

The idea is to have the 'Month' column enumerate by 30 days.
For example, Month = 1 would include days 0-30, Month = 2 would include days 31-60, etc...
The DaysAtSuccess would equal the value in the Day column if the value is equal to or greater than the lower value at each month.
I am working on creating the data set using the mutate (dplyr) and ifelse functions but so far no luck. Any insight would be appreciated.

Edit:

Using the following code, I have been able to generate a 'Month' column:

df$Month <-ceiling(df$Days/30)

Which generates the following data set:

```
   ID  Completed Days Month
  001        Yes   65     3
  002         No   NA    NA
  003        Yes  120     4
  004        Yes   22     1
```

Comment: What is `.`? Is it `NA`?

Comment: I don't know if I get what you want, but maybe `df$DaysAtSuccess <- df$Days*(df$Success == "Yes")*(cieling(df$Days/30) == df$month)`?

Comment: @PedroAlencar Didn't seem to work, I believe the code won't work as the column df$month is not in the original data frame.

Comment: Hi @statsguyz, could you create the month column in the original dataframe with `df$month <- ceiling(df$Days/30)`?

Comment: @PedroAlencar Yes, that worked to generate a 'Month' column. I will add this to the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your data

```
tibble::tribble(
  ~ID, ~Completed, ~Days,
  "001", "Yes",      65,
  "002", "No",       NA,
  "003", "Yes",      120,
  "004", "Yes",      22
) -> your_data
```

I would do

```
library(tidyverse)

your_data %>%
  pmap(\(ID, Completed, Days) {
    map(seq(30, max(.$Days, na.rm = T), 30),
        ~ tibble(ID = ID,
                 Month = .x / 30,
                 Success = ifelse(!is.na(Days) & Days <= .x, "Yes", "No"),
                 DaysAtSuccess = ifelse(Days <= .x, Days, NA)))
  }) %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  arrange(Month)
```

returning

```
# A tibble: 16 x 4
   ID    Month Success DaysAtSuccess
   <chr> <dbl> <chr>           <dbl>
 1 001       1 No                 NA
 2 002       1 No                 NA
 3 003       1 No                 NA
 4 004       1 Yes                22
 5 001       2 No                 NA
 6 002       2 No                 NA
 7 003       2 No                 NA
 8 004       2 Yes                22
 9 001       3 Yes                65
10 002       3 No                 NA
11 003       3 No                 NA
12 004       3 Yes                22
13 001       4 Yes                65
14 002       4 No                 NA
15 003       4 Yes               120
16 004       4 Yes                22
```